# Download apps in ubuntu software centre

Tags: software-center, password, authentication

I am having a problem authenticating in Ubuntu 12.04. I have no password. I have bought my computer online. There is no password when I log in. It's showing me unsuccessful password. So I cannot download any app from the Ubuntu software system.

Comment: Uhhh? What is your problem? Please make your post legible.

Comment: I think your problem is: You have no password for current user and when you want to download any App from Software Center, it ask you enter your password?

Comment: @LolzMe If an answer helped, please mark it as accepted. If it did not, please comment that it didn't help you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your problem is that you THINK your computer has no password, while it really does. There is (fortunately) a simple way to test.

1. Open a commandline by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type `sudo -s` and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
3. If it doesn't ask you for a password, set one. More info below.
4. If it DOES ask you for a password, you need to recover and set a new one.

To set a password:

1. Open a commandline by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type `sudo passwd $(USER)` and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
3. Enter a new password
4. Celebrate with your new password!

To RESET a password:

1. Reboot and hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while rebooting.
2. Enter Ubuntu Recovery mode.
3. Select the `root` menu option.
4. Type `ls /home`. You should see a single directory. Remember the name of it!
5. Type `passwd <insert dir name from above>`.
6. Choose a new password.
7. Done!

Please only do the reset on your own computer! <s>It can reset other Ubuntu passwords as well!</s> Ignore that lie.

---

If you got a new computer pre-loaded with Ubuntu on it, I ***highly recommend*** that you install a clean Ubuntu! It gets rid of manufacturer bloatware, and you never run into these problems.

Answer (score 1):

As the computer seller did not inform you about passwords you are not "your computer" owner. So asking the question: "how to reset the root password?" is not enough. You must be the owner. I suggest you to install the latest Ubuntu version (by now 16.04 - Xenial ) And an extra step related to your motherboard in order to get control over your hardware:

solution steps:

1. Download Ubuntu (current stable version desktop .iso)
2. Burn a DVD
3. Reboot your computer and press F2 or F11 (for most computers) to edit your hardware settings
4. If you are asked for password you need to reset the motherboard
   4.1 cancel and switch off your machine
   4.2 unplug it from power sources
   4.3 open the case
   4.4 remove the onboard battery by 1 or 2 minutes
   4.5 restore the onboard battery 
   4.6 plug power sources and return to step 3. Now you are the owner of your hardware
5. change boot settings: first DVD or USB port depending on where you save your Ubuntu installer.
6. save changes
7. insert your DVD or plug your USB Ubuntu installer
8. Select Save Changes and exit... The installer begins ...
9. Follow and ask installation questions.

Enjoy YOUR computer.